# Spring (Boot) validation annotations for different layers on the same class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Given a web application with *Spring Boot*, *Spring MVC* and *Spring Data* (with *MongoDB* as a database) and a one class used to represent request  on multiple layers (REST, service, persistence).

Is it possible to declarative specify validation constraints on the fields of the class such that some of them would apply only for certain layers (or will be ignored by some) ?

Example:

**Entity** (getter and setter autogenerated)

```
 public class User {

     private String name;

     @NotEmpty
     private String role;
 }
```

where `@NotEmpty` is *JSR 303* anotation

**REST API layer**

`role` does not exist here

```
@RestController
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @PostMapping
    public User register(@Valid User u) {
        return service.createAppUser(u);
    }
}
```

**Service layer**

`role` is set by the implementation and is required by the persistence layer

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo repo;

    private User createAppUser(User u) {
        u.setRole("APP_USER");
        return repo.save(u);
    }
}
```

where `repo` is *Spring Data* `MongoRepository`.

I can think of two approaches which solve this:

1. Introduce DTO object for REST API layer
2. Manual/ procedural validation; either using *Spring* `Validator` or something else, doesn't matter - simply nothing declarative

Both of which I don't like very much as they require lot of boilerplate and this is a trivial case.

Comment: Use validation groups. Specify in your annotations to which groups they apply and on the different levels specify the groups you want to validate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use validation group and `@Validated` annotation.

like this:

**Entity**

```
@NotEmpty(groups = Create.class)
```

**Method**

```
public User register(@Validated(Create.class) User u) {
    return service.createAppUser(u);
}
```

Comment: What's create.class here?

Comment: @ammy it's an empty  interface.